# Who is the best engineering team - question

Tags: interrogatives, question-words

So, today we had a discussion about the following question, which is the title of a competition proposal in our company: "Who is the best engineering team?"

The discussion was about whether it should've instead been written: "Which is the best engineering team?"

We are aware that "which" has to be used in phrases like: "Which engineering team is best?", however it seems unnatural to us (non-native speakers) to say "Which is the best engineering team?"

I couldn't find any similar questions here or elsewhere, so I hope it's not a duplicate. Although it must be trivial to others, we had a long discussion about it.

Comment: "Team" is a collective noun that can be construed as a group of people, so it's fine to use "who", though it would require a plural verb, i.e. "are". That would be my preference, since it retains the personal touch.

Comment: Thank you. Is the sentence "Which is the best team?" even correct? It doesn't sound right compared to "Which team is best?".

Comment: Yes, it's fine to phrase it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be phrased either as "Who are the best (engineering) team?" or as "Which is the best (engineering) team?"

In the first case, the team is a group of people, i.e. a collective noun, so it's acceptable to use "who" (with the plural *are* as noted in comments by BillJ).

This then gives the form:

> Who are the best team?
>
> They are the best team.
>   Bill, Dave and Ted are the best team.
>   Wilhelmina, Davina and Edwina are the best team.

It can also be phrased:

> Which is the best team?
>
> Watford is the best team.
>   Borussia Dortmund is the best team.
>   The best team is the Miami Dolphins.

In this case *team* is a single entity and so the singular form of *to be*, *is*, is used.